# Regex only solution for matching the single occurence without a prefix within a string

Tags: regex, string-matching

Suppose I have a string that can have parameters

`--true config --false`

All parameters can be prefixed by a predetermined prefix like `--` or `!` and they can occur at any place in the string, before or after the "non parameter".

Using `only` regex, how can I match all the "non-parameters" in the string, e.g in the example above it would be `config`.

I've looked at other answers suggesting a negative look aheads such as 
`^(?!--).*` but those only work for the whole string itself.

Comment: Maybe `\s(\w+)\b`

Comment: @MDR There are several issues with this solution, but the main one it will not match non-parameters containing, say, hyphens, and other special chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\S)(?!--|!)\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXPw5a/4).

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a non-whitespace
- `(?!--|!)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a `--` or `!` substring
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

Comment: It works, thank you very much, but is it possible to exclude more than one parameter at a time, like 
 `!true config --false` ?

Comment: @soz Yes, I was on it. Sorry, hit the post button too early. I updated the answer.

Comment: How would I go about specifying two character prefixes like for example '--' or '->'

Comment: The exact prefix I need would be `c>` and `--`

Comment: @soz Then use `(?<!\S)(?!--|c>)\S+`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXPw5a/3)